# What are all of the coordinate systems in convertXY in R?

Tags: r, graphics, plot, bitmap, coordinate-systems

I have a map I've made using spplot, and I would like to add a bitmap graphic to the corner of the graphic, within the boundaries of the plot.  I am using grid.raster to add the graphic, and I believe I need to use grconverX and grcovertY.  However, I am really confused about all of the coordinate systems.

According to [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/convertXY.html) documentation, ConvertXY can convert between: user coordinates ('user'), inches ('inches'), the device coordinate system ('device'), normalized device coordinates ('ndc'), normalized figure coordinates ('nfc'), normalized plot coordinates ('npc') and normalized inner region coordinates ('nic').  There are also a lot of possible units/coordinate systems given in [the documentation for unit objects](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/unit.html), which I need for grid.raster(), and none of them match with the coordinate systems given in convertXY!  The only exception is 'npc', although this stands for 'Normalized plot coordinates' in ConvertXY and 'Normalized Parent Coordinates' in Units, so it is unclear if they are the same.

What do all of these different coordinate systems refer to, and which ones should I be using to anchor a small bitmap to the boundaries of my plot?